# Insert not working in Nodejs and Mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a table called 'Usuarios' in a database called 'hss' when I click on any of the buttons the code doesn't work.
I tried just doing a normal insert with:connection.query("INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOMBRE,APELLIDO) VALUES ('A','B')") but it doesn't work either.

HTML

```
<button onclick="doinsert(); return false;">Reservar!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="doinsert()">Go</button>
<input type = "button" value ="input" onclick ="doinsert();" />
</form>
```

Node

```
function doinsert(){
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password : 'passroot',
        database : 'hss'
    })

    connection.connect();

    var post  = {nombre: 'op', apellido: 'Hello MySQL'};
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO usuarios SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    });
    console.log(query.sql);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run node from a browser, this isn't how it works. You'll need to use ajax or a post request to trigger that to run on the server where the database is.

I'd suggest you look at something like [express](http://expressjs.com/), you'll want to use that code on a post page where you can submit the form to.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it. I'll take a look at express.